# my jar file created from a maven project with all its dependencies is executable but it doesn't launch its main class

Tags: java, spring, maven, ssh, executable-jar

I'm new in maven and spring-boot, i downloaded a maven project (ssh emulator via web interface) form  [github](https://github.com/rahmanusta/ssh-on-web)

I tried to make this project an executable jar so that i can use it later on my web-application project in order to provide the users the ability of using an ssh emulator.

I read some documents and learn how to create an executable jar file with all dependencies from maven.

After taping this command `java -jar jar_file_with_all_dependencies.jar` the spring boot returns this message

```
 Starting ApplicationStarter on admin-PC with PID 37824 (C:\
 Developement\maven-repo\ssh-on-web-master\target\ssh-on-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT-  jar-   with-dependencies.jar started by admin in C:\Developement\maven-repo\ssh-  on-web-  master\target)
  2016-03-30 14:21:48.856  INFO 37824 --- [               main]ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplication       Context@49fc609f: startup date [Wed Mar 30 14:21
   :48 GMT+01:00 2016]; root of context hierarchy
   2016-03-30 14:21:49.328  INFO 37824 --- [           main]      s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s):     8081/http
    2016-03-30 14:21:49.528  INFO 37824 --- [           main]     o.apache.catalina.core
    .StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
     2016-03-30 14:21:49.528  INFO 37824 --- [           main]      org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache      Tomcat/8.0.15
       2016-03-30 14:21:49.619  INFO 37824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.  [Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
     2016-03-30 14:21:49.620  INFO 37824 --- [ost-startStop-1]     o.s.web.context.ContextLoader  : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization   completed in 764ms
     2016-03-30 14:21:49.690  INFO 37824 --- [           main]  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTask
    Scheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService       'defaultSockJsTaskScheduler'
    2016-03-30 14:21:49.880  INFO 37824 --- [           main]  o.s.w.s.handler.Simple
   UrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/shell/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler]
    2016-03-30 14:21:49.960  INFO 37824 --- [           main]   s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081/http
    2016-03-30 14:21:49.960  INFO 37824 --- [           main] com.kodcu.ApplicationStarter  : Started ApplicationStarter in 1.334 seconds (JVM    running for 1.585)
```

This message means the jar file started its main-class but in reality nothing happened. why my web browser doesn't launch automatically the localhost page so i can manipulate the ssh emulator? Do i need to type something else in the url?

For more details :
Main class:

```
    package com.kodcu;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
    import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
    import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.PerConnectionWebSocketHandler;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableWebSocket


    public class ApplicationStarter implements WebSocketConfigurer {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(ApplicationStarter.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/shell").withSockJS();
        }

        @Bean
        public WebSocketHandler myHandler() {
            return new PerConnectionWebSocketHandler(ShellSocket.class);
        }



    }
```

ServletInitializer.java :

```
     package com.kodcu;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    @SpringBootApplication

    public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

            @Override
            protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
                    return application.sources(ApplicationStarter.class);
            }
            @Bean
         public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
            factory.setPort(8081);
            factory.setSessionTimeout(50, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            return factory;
        }


    }
```

pom.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
         <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
         <packaging>war</packaging>

          <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/>
            <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <groupId>ssh-on-web</groupId>
        <artifactId>ssh-on-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.hierynomus</groupId>
                <artifactId>sshj</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.expectit</groupId>
                <artifactId>expectit-core</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <!-- nothing here -->
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.kodcu.ApplicationStarter</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

        </build>


    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The command start an embedded Tomcat application server on your host using the port 8081.
The port is defined in your class : factory.setPort(8081);
As I understand your code sample, your only service is a websocket on path /shell
That's all the command line will do for you. 
To see the website you have to open yourself your browser and go on the URL of your application (http://localhost:8081/shell)

Also, check if you don't have an application.properties file that specify your root context using the property "server.context-path". If so you have to put it in your url (http://localhost:8081//shell

Comment: I tried both http://localhost:8081/shell ,  http://localhost:8081//shell and they return http Status 404.

Comment: I edited my pom.xml and change the package type to jar. now when i type localhost:8081/shell  it returns "  Welcome to SockJS!" :(

Answer (score 0):

I changed the package type in the pom.xml from `war` to `jar` .

I also added these lines to the main.class

```
 @Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    factory.setPort(8081);

    return factory;
}
```

I also generated the jar file and execute it and it works 100% when i type `http://localhost:8081/`